# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/dev/asm/commons/Method

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I've been getting this error when running `$mvn gwt:run`:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/dev/asm/commons/Method   
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader$MySingleJsoImplData.<init>(CompilingClassLoader.java:613)  
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader.<init>(CompilingClassLoader.java:982)  
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ShellModuleSpaceHost.onModuleReady(ShellModuleSpaceHost.java:131)   at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:335)    
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:526)   
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)     
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I tried so many ways to remove gwt-dev from the pom.xml still getting the error so I added it as:

```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
       <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
       <version>${version.gwt}</version>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>
```

Complete $ mvn dependency:tree

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ app ---
[INFO] com.myapp:app:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.8.1:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.0:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.appengine:appengine-api-labs:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.appengine:appengine-testing:jar:1.8.0:test
[INFO] +- com.google.appengine:appengine-api-stubs:jar:1.8.0:test
[INFO] +- com.google.appengine:appengine-tools-sdk:jar:1.8.0:test
[INFO] +- com.google.appengine.orm:datanucleus-appengine:jar:1.0.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.datanucleus:datanucleus-core:jar:1.1.5:runtime
[INFO] +- org.datanucleus:datanucleus-jpa:jar:1.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.jdo:jdo2-api:jar:2.3-eb:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.gwt:gwt-servlet:jar:2.5.1:runtime
[INFO] +- com.google.gwt:gwt-user:jar:2.5.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:sources:1.0.0.GA:provided
[INFO] +- com.google.gwt:gwt-dev:jar:2.5.1:runtime
[INFO] +- org.fusesource.restygwt:restygwt:jar:1.4-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.api:gwt-oauth2:jar:0.2:compile
[INFO] +- name.pehl:piriti-dev:jar:0.8:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-assistedinject:jar:3.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.tractionsoftware:gwt-traction:jar:1.5.9-SNAPSHOT:provided
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.CR2:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:sources:4.3.1.Final:provided
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-core-js:jar:2.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.16:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.sourceforge.cssparser:cssparser:jar:0.9.7:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.w3c.css:sac:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.rosaloves:bitlyj:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.googlecode.gwtquery:gwtquery:jar:1.4.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.errai:errai-jpa-client:jar:3.0.0.20140325-M5:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.2.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.2.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.1.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.google.guava:guava-gwt:jar:14.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.errai:errai-ui:jar:3.0.0.20140325-M5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.stanbol:org.apache.stanbol.enhancer.engines.htmlextractor:jar:0.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.clerezza:rdf.core:jar:0.12-incubating:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.osgi:org.osgi.core:jar:4.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.osgi:org.osgi.compendium:jar:4.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.clerezza:utils:jar:0.1-incubating:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.wymiwyg:wymiwyg-commons-core:jar:0.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |           \- commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.lesscss:lesscss:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.mozilla:rhino:jar:1.7R4:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.errai:errai-data-binding:jar:3.0.0.20140325-M5:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.errai:errai-marshalling:jar:3.0.0.20140325-M5:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.errai:errai-cdi-client:jar:3.0.0.20140325-M5:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.errai:errai-ioc-bus-support:jar:3.0.0.20140325-M5:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.errai:errai-navigation:jar:3.0.0.20140325-M5:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] +- javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:1.0-SP4:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.interceptor:jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Beta1:provided
[INFO] |  \- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.errai:errai-bus:jar:3.0.0.20140325-M5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.errai:errai-common:jar:3.0.0.20140325-M5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.errai.reflections:reflections:jar:3.0.0.20140325-M5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- de.benediktmeurer.gwt-slf4j:gwt-slf4j:jar:0.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.errai:errai-config:jar:3.0.0.20140325-M5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.15.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.errai.io.netty:netty:jar:4.0.0.Alpha1.errai.r1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:14.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jgroups:jgroups:jar:3.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.errai:errai-ioc:jar:3.0.0.20140325-M5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.errai:errai-codegen:jar:3.0.0.20140325-M5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.errai:errai-codegen-gwt:jar:3.0.0.20140325-M5:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.errai:errai-javax-enterprise:jar:3.0.0.20140325-M5:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.errai:errai-tools:jar:3.0.0.20140325-M5:compile
[INFO] |  \- hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:1.8.0.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.mvel:mvel2:jar:2.1.Beta8:compile
[INFO] +- org.sgx:momentgwt:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.sgx:gwtjsutil:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.errai:errai-jaxrs-client:jar:3.0.0.20140325-M5:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.errai:errai-jaxrs-provider:jar:3.0.0.20140325-M5:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.resteasy:jaxrs-api:jar:2.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO] +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0-rc3:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2-b02:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-servlet:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-web:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.freemarker:freemarker-gae:jar:2.3.19:compile
[INFO] +- org.json:json:jar:20090211:compile
[INFO] +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.scribe:scribe:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.beanshell:bsh:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-guice:jar:3.0-beta-3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:jar:3.0-beta-3:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.scannotation:scannotation:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.1.GA:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-multipart-provider:jar:3.0-beta-3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxb-provider:jar:3.0-beta-3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.5-2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.james:apache-mime4j:jar:0.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jackson-provider:jar:3.0-beta-3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.9.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jettison-provider:jar:3.0-beta-3:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-appengine:jar:1.17.0-rc:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.17.0-rc:compile
[INFO] +- org.tuckey:urlrewritefilter:jar:4.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-6.0:pom:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.resource:jboss-connector-api_1.5_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb:jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.xml:jaxrpc-api:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.el:jboss-el-api_2.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.security.jacc:jboss-jacc-api_1.4_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.enterprise.deploy:jboss-jad-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.security.auth.message:jboss-jaspi-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.registry:jboss-jaxr-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.jms:jboss-jms-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet.jsp:jboss-jsp-api_2.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet:jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.bind:jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.rpc:jboss-jaxrpc-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.soap:jboss-saaj-api_1.3_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.ws:jboss-jaxws-api_2.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.faces:jsf-api:jar:2.0.3-b05:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.jws:jsr181-api:jar:1.0-MR1:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-container:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-core:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.test:arquillian-test-api:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.core:arquillian-core-api:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.test:arquillian-test-spi:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.core:arquillian-core-spi:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-api:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-api:jar:1.0.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-spi:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-spi:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.core:arquillian-core-impl-base:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.test:arquillian-test-impl-base:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-impl-base:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.config:arquillian-config-api:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.config:arquillian-config-impl-base:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi:jar:2.0.0-alpha-3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-impl-base:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-impl-base:jar:1.0.1:test
[INFO] |     \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-spi:jar:1.0.1:test
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.7.5:test
[INFO] +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-javaee:jar:2.0.0-alpha-3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-javaee:jar:2.0.0-alpha-3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base:jar:2.0.0-alpha-3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-base:jar:2.0.0-alpha-3:compile
[INFO] +- org.mindrot:jbcrypt:jar:0.3m:compile
[INFO] +- org.bitbucket.dollar:dollar:jar:1.0-beta2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
[INFO] \- com.postmark:postmark-client:jar:0.3.2:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO]    +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]       +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]       +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]       |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]       |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]       |  \- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]       \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have custom GWT generators or linkers, then you shouldn't need `gwt-dev` in your POM.
In case you need it, it should be with `<scope>provided</scope>` or `<optional>true</optional>` so as to not be included in the generated WAR (though honestly, you should not mix client-side and server-side code in the same Maven module, but that's another story).

That being said, the `com.google.gwt.dev.asm.commons.Method` class exists in `gwt-dev` for at least 5 years; and you do have `gwt-dev` in your classpath (added by the `gwt-maven-plugin` anyway) because otherwise you wouldn't be able to launch the DevMode (all the other classes in the stack trace come from `gwt-dev`).

I'd check that the `gwt-dev` is not corrupted. Maybe just clean `~/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt` so Maven re-downloads everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the dependency without scope, like this:

```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
       <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
       <version>${version.gwt}</version>
   </dependency>
```